# Is there a minimum number of tokens I need to have to bake on Carthagenet?

Tags: baking, baking-node, testing

I have gotten about 236 odd tokens from the faucet and now I am about to register to bake on my node.
The problem is I can't seem to find any mention on the minimum number of tokens required to bake on Carthagenet. Is there a requirement such as 8000xtz on this network as well? If so how would I get enough to test out baking?

Thank you.

Comment: As Carthagenet runs the Cathage protocol, it should requires, at least, a roll of 8000Xtz to be able to bake. The documentation regarding protocols can be found here (for Athens): https://tezos.gitlab.io/protocols/004_Pt24m4xi.html

Comment: Note that other constants of the protocol in test networks can differ.

Comment: Thanks but how do I get 8000Xtz? The faucet only drips a tiny amount.

Comment: For test network, you should use https://faucet.tzalpha.net/ .Sometimes, the faucet is not very generous but you can as many faucet account as you want, and then, transfer the tokens on a single account. You can ask as many account as you want, but "please drink responsibly".